# Listen to newly created Liquidity Pool

Tags: liquiditypool

Hi Im new to development of discord bot
So i was trying to create a bot that will get the newly created Liquidity Pools or Burnt Liquidity pools

is there a way in helius to do this?
[image]

not sure on what to put in transaction type or account address

Comment: This looks like a question for the Helius team.